# Laravel 5.8 - Auth::user() with different guards

Tags: laravel, authentication

Lets say I have the following guards:

```
  'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

I login to my app as a normal user using the default 'web' guard and to access the authenticated user I can use the following:  `$user = Auth::user();`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

}

public function edit()
{
    $user = Auth::user();


}
```

At the same time I also login to the same app as an admin using the 'admin' guard and in admin controllers I have the following middleware and to access the authenticated admin I do the following: `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');

}

public function edit()
{
    $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

}
```

The question is do I need to specify the guard each time to access the admin user - I've noticed once I've authenticated in constructor using `$this->middleware('auth:admin')` I no longer need to specify the guard to access the authenticated user inside other controller methods? Is this correct behaviour

Comment: The middlewares run at every time that you get a request on your laravel.

The auth middleware just check if you call the function `$this->middleware('auth:admin');` if the user logged in has the expected login information on session.
The `Auth::guard()` function checks if the current user has a specific permission. Note that we have authentication level and permission level.

Comment: the `auth` middleware will set the default guard for you so you dont have to specify the guard after the `auth` middleware has ran

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your `admin` guard isn't doing anything different to the `web` guard. It's using the same driver and the same provider. So there is absolutely no difference between using `Auth::user()` and `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`.

If you do decide to implement a custom driver (different to the `session` driver) for your `admin` guard, you'll need to use `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` (or set your guard as default) when accessing the authenticated user. Otherwise, `Auth::user()` will look for user details in the session.

As a side note, the default `session` driver caches the user instance on first retrieval which in your case is when the request hits the `auth` middleware. Subsequent calls to `Auth::user()` or `Auth::guard('admin')->user()` are handled by returning the user instance from cache.